# C++ convert TCP Socket to BIO (OpenSSL)

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl

First of all I did search for my problem, but it's not easy to find answers to exactly this topic.

I wrote a small C++ program that connects through a SOCKS5 Proxy to a HTTP website. That's all working well. Now I want to connect to a HTTPS website, and that's causing some trouble..

The problem is that I cant directly create a BIO* and connect to the SOCKS5 Proxy, I need to do the SOCKS5 protocol stuff first with a unencrypted socket, and then convert that to a BIO*. Am I right with this?

So i got this code snipped for the normal TCP->SOCKS5->Website stuff:

```
SOCKS5_Greeting_Response socks_gresp;
SOCKS5_Command_Response socks_cresp;
int sock = createSocket();

socketConnect(sock, "127.0.0.1", 9050);

socks_gresp = socketWriteSOCKS5Greeting_TOR(sock);

if(socks_gresp.Version == 5){

    std::cout << "[i] Version match!" << std::endl;

}

socks_cresp = SOCKS5_Connect(sock, get_IPv4("www.google.de"), 80);

if(socks_cresp.Reply == 0){

    std::cout << "[i] Connection success!" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 1){

    std::cout << "[i] General server error" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 3){

    std::cout << "[i] Network not reachable" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 5){

    std::cout << "[i] Connection refused!" << std::endl;

}
```

After that I can read/write to/from sock, I don't want to post all the sub-functions cause it would be too much...

Well I read here: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205813/convert-existing-tcp-socket-into-tls-using-openssl) that I should use `BIO_new_socket()` and `SSL_set_bio()`
I found here a code snipped: [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359896/openssl-rsa-and-winsock-and-c)

So here is my current code snipped, trying to convert the TCP Socket to BIO* (without all the error handling stuff, I include that when all is working):

```
SSL_library_init();

SOCKS5_Greeting_Response socks_gresp;
SOCKS5_Command_Response socks_cresp;
int sock = createSocket();

socketConnect(sock, "127.0.0.1", 9050);

socks_gresp = socketWriteSOCKS5Greeting_TOR(sock);

if(socks_gresp.Version == 5){

    std::cout << "[i] Version match!" << std::endl;

}

socks_cresp = SOCKS5_Connect(sock, get_IPv4("www.google.de"), 443);

if(socks_cresp.Reply == 0){

    std::cout << "[i] Connection success!" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 1){

    std::cout << "[i] General server error" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 3){

    std::cout << "[i] Network not reachable" << std::endl;

}
else if(socks_cresp.Reply == 5){

    std::cout << "[i] Connection refused!" << std::endl;

}

//--

BIO* sslsock = BIO_new_socket(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_CTX * ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/cacert.pem", NULL);
SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

SSL_set_bio(ssl, sslsock, sslsock);

std::cout << "[i] SSL Write: " << SSL_write(sslsock, generate_basic_GET_request("www.google.de","Mozilla","")) << std::endl;

std::cout << SSL_read(sslsock) << std::endl;

SSL_Close_Connection(sslsock);

//--

closeSocket(sock);
```

My SSL_write() will print out < 0 on error and else the bytes send. This is my output:

```
[i] Version match!
[i] Connection success!
[i] SSL Write: 191
F
```

Instead of the 'F' I should see the HTML source or HTTP response there.. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something false at the creation of the BIO*, but I cant tell what. Anyone here can?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is no different than other situations that need to start unencrypted and then upgrade to SSL/TLS at a later time, like `STARTTLS` on SMTP.  So yes, there are ways to accomplish that with OpenSSL's BIO API.

OpenSSL has its own `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()` functions that expect an `SSL*` as input.  You are calling `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()` functions that take a `BIO*` as input, and are reading/writing `std::string` values directly.  So you have clearly overloaded the native functions with custom functions.  And the fact that you are passing a `BIO*` leads me to think that you are likely calling `BIO_write()` and `BIO_read()` inside those functions.  When using `SSL_set_bio()`, you need to use the native `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()` functions to read/write directly with the `SSL*`.  Internally they will use the associated `BIO*` for the lower-level socket I/O as needed.

That being said, while the above will work, it is also not the only way to use the BIO API for this situation.  An alternative approach would be to use `BIO_new_ssl_connect()` to create a `BIO` chain consisting of an SSL/TLS `BIO` and a socket connect `BIO` linked together.  Call `BIO_do_connect()` to connect to the SOCKS proxy, then use `BIO_find_type(BIO_TYPE_SOCKET)` to retrieve the socket `BIO*` from the chain and use `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()` on it to perform unencrypted SOCKS I/O as needed.  When ready, call `BIO_do_handshake()` on the SSL/TLS `BIO*` to initiate the SSL/TLS handshake (which will pass through the already-connected socket `BIO*`), and then use `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()` on the SSL/TLS `BIO*` to perform encrypted I/O as needed.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: don't use OpenSSL BIO, use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) instead.

Comment: OpenSSL BIO works just fine for what the OP is asking for.  You ust have to know how to use it.

Comment: When you seem to know it, why not telling me?

Comment: Well, true, but then curl documentation is much more thorough and there is less cryptic bullsh*t you have to carry with you to just perform an SSL connection, so I'd go with libcurl anyway. Not to say that OpenSSL's security history leaves a lot to be desired.